# Pass HTML hidden field value in @HTML.BeginForm

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to pass a hidden field value on click of submit button into my action method. This needs to happen on click of a button which posts a file. Below is the Razor code for HTML form with Post method that accepts the file.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadProject", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{
        <label id="lblProjectSize" hidden="hidden">Select Project size</label>
        <select id="ddlProjectSize">
            <option value="1">Large</option>
            <option value="2">Medium</option>
            <option value="3">Small</option>
        </select>
    <input type="hidden" id="hdnProjectSize" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Data" onclick="setHiddenVal()" />
}
```

This is the action method I have-

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> UploadProject(string UploadProjectOption, int? ProjectId, HttpPostedFileBase PostedFile)
{
    //code here
}
```

I am able to access the file object in the action method but I am not sure how to pass an additional parameter through the submitted form.

As of I am setting the the hidden field value on click of submit button after which I need to access the hidden field value in the posted action method.

Script to set hidden field value-

```
function setHiddenVal()
{
    alert($("#ddlProjectSize :selected").val());
    $("#hdnProjectSize").val($("#ddlProjectSize :selected").val());
}
```

I don't wan't to use AJAX for this.

Comment: Where is your hidden input? And what is the `setHiddenVal()` script?

Comment: `@Html.HiddenFor`, or construct the html yourself.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Please check the updated post.

Comment: Your input does not have a `name` attribute so it does not post a value. It needs to match the name of the parameter you want to bind to. But what is the point of your hidden input and script? - you may as well just give the `<select>` the `name` attribute (I assume you want to bind the value to `UploadProjectOption` (in which case that parameter should be `int` and the `<select>` should have `name="UploadProjectOption"`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Your comment solved my problem but I accepted the first answer post. Thanks Stephen!

Comment: Sorry to be harsh, but you really need to buy yourself a good book or at least work through the tutorials on the mvc site to understand the basics. In mvc you use models and create views using `HtmlHelper` methods to bind to the model

Comment: @StephenMuecke Completely agree with you. I am slightly new to MVC. ViewModels are always preferable. But somehow I landed on a hot fix issue so I can't change it in the desired/ideal way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should set `name` attribute for input types and you defined `onclick` event on the submit and of course you can't trigger the form action. Define `onchange` event for select option instead.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadProject", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
{
    <label id="lblProjectSize" hidden="hidden">Select Project size</label>
    <select id="ddlProjectSize" name = "ddlProjectSize" onchange="setHiddenVal()">
        <option value="1">Large</option>
        <option value="2">Medium</option>
        <option value="3">Small</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" id="hdnProjectSize" name = "hdnProjectSize"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Data" />
}
```

Comment: The whole script, and having a hidden input is just pointless, but of course you can handle the submit event if you want to.